# Array_Key_Exists... 0 != 0 / Working local, not working on server?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key, associative-array

I wrote a script which is supposed to create a repeater array based on the name as key in my $GLOBALS array. But it dons't work.

The script says, that the name wasn't found. You can see for which name I'm looking at the bottom of this page: [debug.txt](http://hartbodenreiniger.info/wp-admin/debug.txt)

At the beginning you can see my array in which I search for the key. And you can also see, that the names exists as key who I'm looking for...
The names who are printed at the bottom of the name are the needles the script is working with.

So, I tried to to check if the method `array_key_exists(...)` is getting the key 0. But also, the method doesn't found the key in my array...
As you can see in the last line of the debug.txt file...

I'm checking it like this:

```
if(array_key_exists(0, $GLOBALS["productsXML"])){
        fwrite($myfile, "\n\n JA! 0 = 0");
    }else{
        fwrite($myfile, "\n\n NEIN! 0 != 0");
    }
```

And to check the names I use this one to search for the keys:

```
function searchForGameXML($title){
    if(array_key_exists($title, $GLOBALS["productsXML"])){
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The $title is the needle at the bottom of the page as you can see. But I don't get, why the method isn't finding the key...

And now it comes. I tested this code local on my PC. And there it is working... exactly the same code... I don't get it..
Where is the error? Why is even 0 not found in the array?

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: It's hard to tell. Exactly the same file? Local on Windows, Server on Linux? Maybe there are issues with charset? Do you have any more code to share - so it's easier to see what's going on?

Comment: I know now why there is nothing... because the array is empty.. I created a new question for that -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415021/global-array-gets-deleted-wp-all-import-function-php